# Manually scrolling through a TComboBox

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7, delphi-2010

I have not been able to figure out why I am unable to manually scroll through a TComboBox component when I programatically cause the drop down pick list to appear.  Here is the code I am using:

```
SendMessage(ComboBox1.handle, CB_SHOWDROPDOWN, Integer(True), 0);
```

This causes the drop down pick list to appear. However, if I try to use my keyboard and use the up and down arrow keys, the drop down pick list immediately closes.  How do I keep the list from auto-closing when using the keyboard up/down navigation keys?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate the ComboBox. And you'd better use the `DroppedDown` property, which also invalidates the combobox to reflect the change.

```
ActiveControl := ComboBox1;
ComboBox1.DroppedDown := True;
```

Comment: Worth noting that OP's `CB_SHOWDROPDOWN` is only one of a larger set of window messages required to recreate the full sequence of activating and dropping down a combobox (which is why it doesn't work on its own).  Agreed that this is preferable approach.

Comment: Adding ActiveControl := ComboBox1; and ComboBox1.DroppedDown := True; to the code makes no difference. The drop down list still continues to auto-close as soon as the down arrow key is touched.

Comment: @user - With my test here, with a brand new form having a button and a combobox, activating the combobox makes the difference. Actually if I don't activate it, the items cannot be changed with the keyboard but the dropdown doesn't close either. I suggest you to do the same and try this with a new project.

Comment: @J... Either will end up in SetActiveControl. To the first comment - Yeah, DroppedDown also invalidates the combo client rectangle. Incorporated to the answer.